# How to allow mulipule dateformat in MudBlazor datepicker?

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

```
  <MudDatePicker @bind-Date="model.Date"
                                   Validation="@(_modelValidator.ValidateValue)"
                                         For="@(() => model.Date)"
                                         Editable="true" Margin="Margin.Dense" Label="Lab Out" Variant="Variant.Outlined"></MudDatePicker>
```

Allow all Dateformat { "MM/dd/yyyy", "M/d/yy", "M/dd/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy", "M/dd/yy", "MM/d/yy" }

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a custom component

   ```
   public class CustomDateComponent : MudDatePicker    
   {        

   [Parameter]
   public string[] AllowedFormats { get; set; } = { "MM/dd/yyyy", 
    "M/d/yy", "M/dd/yyyy", "MM/d/yyyy", "M/dd/yy", "MM/d/yy" };

   [Parameter]
   public string DisplayFormat { get; set; } = "MM/dd/yyyy";

   protected override Task StringValueChanged(string value)
   {
       foreach (var format in AllowedFormats)
       {
           if (DateTime.TryParseExact(value, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime parsedDate))
           {
               value = parsedDate.ToString(DisplayFormat);
               base.OnDayClicked(parsedDate);
               break;
           }
       }
       DateFormat = DisplayFormat;
       return base.StringValueChanged(value);
   }
   ```
2. Use in blazor

   ```
   <CustomDateComponent @bind-Date="model.Date" 
                                    Validation="@(_modelValidator.ValidateValue)"
                                    For="@(() => model.Date)"
                                    Editable="true" Margin="Margin.Dense" Label="Lab Out" Variant="Variant.Outlined"></CustomDateComponent>
   ```